# tkz-euclide label point at centre of node

Tags: tkz-euclide

How can I place a point label exactly over the top of a node using `tkz-euclide`? I know it can be done with `tikz` using something like `\node (A) at (1,1) {A};`.

Is there any equivalent using `tkz-euclide`, like eg, `\tkzLabelPoint[center](1,1){A}`?

The `\tkzLabelPoint` options include `above, below, above left, below right`, etc, but if I leave the position option blank it defaults to `below right`.  I can do something like `\tkzLabelPoint[above, yshift=-12](1,1){A}`, but this seems like an unsatisfactory work-around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `anchor=center` (`\tkzLabelPoint` is just a node with predefined style).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw[gray](0,0)grid(2,2);
\tkzInit[xmin=0,ymin=0,xmax=2,ymax=2]
\tkzGrid[gray]
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
\tkzLabelPoint[red,anchor=center](A){$A$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use a shorthand for `anchor=center`: `\tkzLabelPoint[red,centered](A){$A$}`